# Is there a full reference of supported style (CSS) statements in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

is ther anyone that has a full reference of working CSS statements in TCPDF?

I tried to look on the site but i found nothing!

Thx

Comment: I couldn't find it either. Not on their site, and not by Googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any as far as I know. Your only chance is to inspect the source code yourself and, even then, it's still not very clear what rule applies to what element.

Comment: In any case, as a general rule you should not rush to accept an answer that claims "can't be done". It can always be wrong :)

Comment: Ok, i uncheck it, but i got a strong feeling that your answer is the right one!hope that someone proves me wrong! :)